# Use a JTable from a list in a for-each

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I use Java Spring MVC in my webapplication. I need to make a table in JTable from a list that belongs to a Java Object (locally called *table* in for-each loop, as you can see below). 
So for each *table*, there's a *table.listOfThings* (a java.util.List object) I have to show inside JTable.

**HTML:**

```
c:forEach var="table" items="${listOfTables}">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 data-cell">
          <div class="data-label">
            <b><fmt:message key="thisTitle" />:</b>
            <div id="jTableContainer"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And the **JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    readyTable();
)};

function readyTable(){
     $('#jTableContainer').jtable({
         title: 'List Title',
         actions: {
             listAction: ${table.listOfThings},
         },
         fields: {
             Field: {
                 key: true,
                 title: 'Field',
                 width: auto; 
         }
     });

    $("#jTableContainer").jtable("load"); 
}
```

This way, JTable is always empty - it just display the title. How can I do it?

Comment: i dont think jquery has access to the default page response attributes....but I may be wrong, isn't jquery built when the page is already loaded?

Comment: Maybe I need to pass the local attribute to the JS in some way?

Comment: I'm only guessing, I know you can access response stuff in document ready, maybe try passing it to that function like readyTable(${table.listOfThings}); or maybe set a global variable which is given a value during ready(), have a play and use the debugger if you're using chrome, or console.log(${table.listOfThings}) in your ready() to see what's going on.

Comment: Well, actually it worked. Now I got another problem: even if in debug console the ${table.listOfThings} is passed in the JTable, the table is still empty. I will work further into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can access response stuff in document ready, maybe try passing it to that function like `readyTable(${table.listOfThings});` or maybe set a global variable which is given a value during `ready()`, have a play and use the debugger if you're using chrome, or `console.log(${table.listOfThings})` in your `ready()` to see what's going on